# How to make this type of drawable in xml

Tags: android, compound-drawables

I want to make a transparent circle in center of screen and an opaque are on rest of screen. Is this possible with drawable? Or can it be done programmatically.

I have added an image on top of map. Map works perfectly. But problem is I want to support multiple resolutions so I don't want to use different images.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yyafqik996p4avp/AABc8ZMKi4pks_BQutQrbg8aa?dl=0

EDIT:

1)Map image is what is my expected output.
2)Mapfilter image is what i want to create using drawable or programmatically.
3)Output image is what i am getting while using below method.

I used this method to draw the second image
  http://pastebin.com/MUrH8gmS

I set the output bitmap to my image view using setImageBitmap method

**But now the problem is it leaves some space on left and right of image(See Output.png image). How to remove it?**

Comment: before draw the rectangle, clip a circle path on the canvas

Comment: @suitianshi Cliping a circle path gives me an bitmap with circle filled and rest of screen transparent but I want it to be the oppsite.

Comment: add a ` Region.Op` param to your function

Comment: @Sanjay imho you can't do that in xml drawable,  but easly you can do it by writing a custom Shape and pass it to a ShapeDrawable

Comment: @suitianshi I clipped the circle but i am getting some margin left to it.

Comment: @pskink which shape should i use to draw the image?

Comment: @Sanjay class MyShape extends Shape { ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroundOverlay.GroundOverlay` to set the transparent circle image onto the center of the map.

Comment: I don't want to set image . I want to create a drawable shape if possible. I have used a relative layout and set image on top of map.

Comment: @Sanjay imho you can't do that in xml drawable, but easly you can do it by writing a custom Shape and pass it to a ShapeDrawable